# Eloquent's First or Create does not consider the mutator before checking if the record exists?

Tags: laravel

Imagine that I have the following model:

```
class Link extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['path', 'secret'];

    public function setSecretAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['secret'] = sha1($value);
    }
}
```

And the following code:

```
$link = Link::firstOrCreate(['path' => $someValue, 'secret' => $anotherValue]);
```

Is there something wrong with my code or "firstOrCreate" ignore the mutator when it will check if the registry already exists? If it ignores, I just have to add sha1 encryption to "anotherValue" to get the behavior I expect. But my question is, wouldn't that be redundant?

Comment: the accessors and mutators don't come into play for the query to find the record, those fields are directly passed to `where`

Comment: This is the job of your database I think. You might add a `unique()` to your `secret` column in your migration. Or have some logic into your mutator.

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of detail in this question, but if `path` is a unique identifier this is easily done with [the second argument](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#retrieving-or-creating-models) to `Model::firstOrCreate()`.

> If the model can not be found in the database, a record will be inserted with the attributes resulting from merging the first array argument with the optional second array argument.

So your code would look like this:

```php
$link = Link::firstOrCreate(
    ['path' => $someValue],
    ['secret' => $anotherValue]
);
```

---

If both values are required to uniquely identify the record, you can simply do a conditional check:

```php
$link = Link::where('path', $someValue)
    ->where('secret', sha1($anotherValue))
    ->first();

if (!$link) {
    Link::create(['path' => $someValue, 'secret' => $anotherValue]);
}
```

Note that mutators apply only to database writes done via Eloquent methods. When you are reading the database, you must manually hash the value, as I've done.

---

To avoid manually hashing the value, the best option would be a [query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#local-scopes) on the model like so:

```php
class Link extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['path', 'secret'];

    public function setSecretAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['secret'] = sha1($value);
    }

    public function scopeSecretHashOf($query, $secret)
    {
        return $query->where('secret', '=', sha1($secret));
    }
}
```

Which you could then use like this:

```php
$link = Link::where('path', $someValue)
    ->whereSecretHashOf($anotherValue)
    ->first();

if (!$link) {
    Link::create(['path' => $someValue, 'secret' => $anotherValue]);
}
```

In theory you could intercept and rewrite the query with a custom grammar but it would likely be more effort than it's worth.